# Magento adding Cash on Delivery fee when user select paypal

Tags: magento

i encountered an issue that sometimes arises on my Magento Community Edition 1.8 Store. The problem is that sometimes Magento adds the Cash on Delivery fee, to the order grand total, in spite of the user had selected Paypal as payment method. This happen only if the user selects Paypal as payment method and happen rarely. Sometimes even the amounts of the items through Paypal and Magento are not in compliance. Contact Paypal Support was not helpful.

Any help will be appreciate
Thanks in advance to everyone

Kind Regards
Steelwork Media Solutions

Answer (score 1):

I feel like some necroposter, but I want to share some thoughts about solving this issue.

Recently I got the very same problem: user has chosen PayPal as payment method, but got charged with cash on delivery fee. After some investigating, I found out that cash on delivery module itself was a culprit.

The problem is in module's logic: it adds up COD fee when COD payment method is selected, but it DOES NOT clear that fee from quote, when payment method is changed to another one. So, when order is being created, fields with COD fee are being copied as is to order. And client gets charged for nothing.

The worst thing in this situation is that you don't see that fee applied in checkout. It pops up only in order.

For example, there is a part of code from MSP_CashOnDelivery module:

```
if (
($_helper->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() == $_model->getCode()) &&
($address->getAddressType() == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
) {
    $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $amount);
    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $baseAmount);

    $address->setMspCashondelivery($amount);
    $address->setMspBaseCashondelivery($baseAmount);
    $address->setMspCashondeliveryInclTax($amountInclTax);
    $address->setMspBaseCashondeliveryInclTax($baseAmountInclTax);
    $quote->setMspCashondelivery($amount);
    $quote->setMspBaseCashondelivery($baseAmount);
    $quote->setMspCashondeliveryInclTax($amountInclTax);
    $quote->setMspBaseCashondeliveryInclTax($baseAmountInclTax);
}
```

To solve the problem, you need to add following code below:

```
if ($_helper->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() != $_model->getCode())
{
    $address->setMspCashondelivery(0);
    $address->setMspBaseCashondelivery(0);
    $address->setMspCashondeliveryInclTax(0);
    $address->setMspBaseCashondeliveryInclTax(0);
    $quote->setMspCashondelivery(0);
    $quote->setMspBaseCashondelivery(0);
    $quote->setMspCashondeliveryInclTax(0);
    $quote->setMspBaseCashondeliveryInclTax(0);
}
```

Comment: I have had same problem with standard Magento cashondeliver and with an extension that add a fee to a payment method, i think is the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above answer, setting the fields to zero works perfectly. However, it will add a row in invoice and order with a zero charge and that may sound weird to customers. so just add a simple if condition for checking if charge is zero in all the Totals.php block files.

```
$amt = $this->getSource()->getServiceCharge();
$nameAmt = $this->getSource()->getServiceChargeName();
    if ($amt && $amt!=0) {
        $this->addTotalBefore(new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'service_charge',
            'value'     => $amt,
            'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseServiceCharge(),
            'label'     => $nameAmt,
                )), 'service_charge');
    }
```